# Passing an image to MATLAB from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, matlab, image-processing

I require the following to be done in my project.

I have a VB.NET front-end ready and the processing of MATLAB. I need to pass the image from VB.NET to MATLAB for processing. I can call MATLAB functions from VB.NET, but is it possible to pass an image to MATLAB for processing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution here would be to store the image at a temporary location and pass the path to MATLAB as an argument. MATLAB could then read the image and process it as necessary.

I would recommend that a handshake mechanism be implemented as well so that one can rid of the temporary image after it has been read successfully, though this is not a requirement.

Comment: Problem is the time. This is a real time application and I need this transferring to be done quite fast. I suppose this saving image and then reading it would take much time. would it?

Comment: @user2388116: That would of course depend on the image itself. From prior experience, for any reasonable size image (of say, 5 MB or so) it should be well within typical soft real-time timeframes.